# How can i get id of inserted record Using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity

I have a problem with Entity Framework in Asp.net. I want to get the Id value whenever I add a record to the SQL database table. How can I do this?
Here is my code:

```
StoredProcedure 



USE [Sapphiresworld]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[addProduct]    Script Date: 7/4/2018 10:25:41 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Proc [dbo].[addProduct]
@title nvarchar(250),
@price nvarchar(50),
@unitID int,
@date nvarchar(50),
@subCategoryID  int,
@brandID int,
@vat int,
@discount int,
@picture nvarchar(50),
@stock int
as
declare @MyVal int=0
INSERT into [PRODUCT] values (@title,
@price ,
@unitID,
@date,
@subCategoryID  ,
@brandID ,
@vat ,
@discount ,
@picture ,
@stock)
Set @MyVal = @@IDENTITY
Select @MyVal as Val
```

Here is ClsBrand

```
        public string AddBrand(string brandName)
   {
   var result = new SapphiresworldEntities().AddBrand(brandName).ToString();

        return result;       
   }
```

Code against Save Button

```
  protected void Btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            clsBrand nb = new clsBrand();
      string nwBran = nb.AddBrand(relig.Text);

}
```

Comment: I see no Entity Framworkz code in your example

Comment: Yes! there is no EF code. Plz describe more.

Comment: @TheGeneral what should i add more ?

Answer (score 2):

After inserting a record, the Id value will automatically populate. You just take the value like from objectname.Id.

Comment: I need more information. where and What should I add in this code. I want to return the ID of the newly inserted column and save it in `nwBran`

Comment: Please check my another answer in your question. There is an example of Entity Framework.

Answer (score 2):

Complete Solution

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name")] Student student)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(student);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        //Here your Id Value after insert record
        int StudentId = student.Id;

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(student);
}
```

Hope you understand and it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Once you call the save changes methods in Entity framework, ID will automatically be populated(Assuming that you have ID as identity column in you table)

Comment: I need more information.  where and What should I add in this code. I want to return the ID of the newly inserted column and save it in `nwBran` .

Comment: You do not need to select @@IDENTITY in you insert stored procedure. Just make the unique column of your table as identity column(or add on ID column in table and make it identity) and insert a row in table. 

for example:
var cust = new Customer(); 
context.Customers.Add(cust);
context.SaveChanges(); // generates Id for customer
string nwBran = cust.Id; // now you can get the Id(identity) of inserted object

Answer (score 0):

As per the above answers the id value will automatically populate after record will insert.

Here is the example.

your DataModel class ex.

```
public class MyDataModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string TestData {get; set;}
}
```

and when you are going to insert your data using entity framework use this

```
public bool SaveMethodInDataBase(MyDataModel myDataModel)
{
     MyDataModel result = _dbContext.MyDataModel.Add(myDataModel);
     _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

then this `result` will return data with Id. in here `_dbContext` is your EntityFrameWork `SPContext` if you created.

Try This.